# CoreData: efficient way to fetch and relate entities

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have a CoreData database full of objects that relate to each other.

EntityFoo - attribute: uniqueId, relationship: one-to-many to other EntityFoo objects, relationship: one-to-many to other EntityUnresolvedRelationship objects

EntityUnresolvedRelationship - attribute: uniqueId, inverseRelationship: back to EntityFoo object

When my iPhone application starts, I get the information for these objects from a web service.  I parse the web service response and create the Foo entities.  At the time I download and parse the data and put the Foo objects into CoreData I don't want to take the time to find the other EntityFoo objects that need to be related to this object, and it is likely that I do not yet have a Foo object to relate yet if it has not yet been downloaded and parsed, so I quickly make an UnresolvedRelationship object for the relationship and store the uniqueId in it so that I can resolve the relationship for this object later.

Now I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to walk through all of the Foo or UnresolvedRelationship objects and create the proper CoreData relationships between all of the Foo objects.  In other words, in the end I want to have no UnresolvedRelationship objects...this was just temporary...the Foo objects will only have relationships to each other.

There could be 15,000 plus Foo objects.

Is there a good way to fetch all of the Foo objects and all of the UnresolvedRelationship objects in a way that I can walk one of the arrays and quickly find the matching entity in the other array by it's uniqueId so that I can setup the CoreData relationship?

Anyway, would love any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be doing this as part of the parsing of the data coming from the web service.  That is going to be the most efficient way to do it.  The way you are approaching this is that you are ***guessing*** that the relationship lookup is going to be slow.  That is a bad approach to optimization.

Fetching the objects and linking them is not going to be slow unless you cause them to be realized (faulted) into memory.  If you are faulting 15K objects, it is going to be slow anyway.

Set up you relationships while parsing, use autorelease pools effectively during your parsing and reset your context at consistent intervals during the parsing to keep memory down.  That is the best option.

Comment: Thanks Marcus.  I am unable to resolve all of the relationships during parsing time because I do not yet know about all of the objects that I need to relate.  Because of this, it seems like it is a two step process: pull down all of the objects, then setup all of the relationships.  My current approach to resolving is to fetch all of the objects and put them into a lookup dictionary based on the uniqueId.  Then I fetch all of the unresolved objects and walk them and setup the relationships.  I delete the temporary objects as I go and save changes at the end.

Comment: Are you saving the objects out before doing this relationship pairing?

Comment: Yes.  During the downloading and parsing operation I am carefully managing memory with an autorelease pool as you suggest, and I am saving the objects out to the persistent store as I go.